# Adding check marks to Bootstrap button drop-down items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap drop down button:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single

And I would like to add checkmarks (not necessarily checkboxes) to those list items that the user has selected. Is there style already built in do this or does someone already have a solution built for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the dropdown auto-closes onclick, so you might want to check that out as well (as in prevent default behavior). Other than that, you can place whatever you want inside the dropdown-menu, so go nuts.

Comment: Here is a pure css check mark I just made that you can use, http://jsfiddle.net/d4xNe/1/. Otherwise you can just use an image to place inside of it. (I would not suggest a pure css solution since it is impractical)

Comment: Check out the Bootstrap select plugin -- http://bootply.com/107784

Comment: hey thanks! I will check out that plugin!

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution that doesn't require icon fonts or images. This is all the CSS you need:

```
.dropdown-item-checked::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: .4rem;
  content: '✓';
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

### Toggling the Checked State

To add/remove a checkmark, just toggle the `dropdown-item-checked` modifier on the appropriate `dropdown-item`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-checked">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Bootstra dropdown menu with checked item]

### Demo & Source

Demo: https://codepen.io/claviska/pen/aLxQgv

Source: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/adding-a-checked-state-to-bootstrap-4-dropdown-menus

Comment: How do I stop this from applying to my other dropdowns or make it apply to one specific one?

Comment: Add a class to your dropdown and then prefix the .dropdown-item-checked selector with that class name.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution using a Font Awesome icon: http://www.bootply.com/oJgbiXIzBM

Using the same HTML as http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single

The CSS is:

```
.active-tick a::after {
    content: '\f00c'; /* http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/ok/ */
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    float: right;
}
```

And here's an example of mutually exclusive ticks on the options:

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('active-tick').siblings().removeClass('active-tick');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted [claviska's great CSS-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890814/105539) so that it draws it with a rotated box that has 2 bordered sides, and this provides a more modern, geometric look than an HTML entity would provide.

```
.dropdown-item-checked::before
{
position: absolute;
left: 0.8rem;
margin-top: 1px;
content: '';
width: 6px;
height: 12px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
border-right: 3px solid #333;
transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything built into the bootstrap for this.

Firefox and Webkit browser support the `background-image` property on the `option` element:

```
 <option style="background-image:url(check.gif);">Option</option>
```

Otherwise, you will need to resort to a jQuery solution. This is a nice one:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Cant access the above link...looks like it is hacked.